# Adobe Premiere is placing a faint 'X' on video transition

Tags: premiere, adobe

I am transitioning 1 video to a still PSD in Adobe Premiere Pro.

No matter the transition, it overlays a faint red x (It remains there, even on export). I have tried everything to be best of my ability to fix it, though I can't seem to find a solution.

[image: dobe]

Seeking advice on how to resolve this trouble.
Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The kind of X you are seeing usually appears when applying a demo-version of a transition of an effect. Are you sure you are not using some third-party transition pack that you simply haven't bought yet? Try using the standard cross-dissolve and report back if the X remains with native transitions. Cheers!

Comment: Really appreciate the help! I have a subscription to extensions but it seems not to be activated. Super super grateful – I thought I was going crazy!